# Focus on jquery tokeninput element (Chrome and Opera)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-tokeninput

I have a problem with tokeninput element in Chrome and Opera (FF works fine).
When one or more elements are choosen in tokeninput, it cannot loose a focus, cursor is still blinking after a last element, if you click on other elements on page they all are blocked.

The simplified code you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/busiek/439xn9ue/2/

Element definition is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filterYachtModel").tokenInput( 
      [
        {id: 7, name: "Antares"},
        {id: 11, name: "Athena"},
        {id: 13, name: "Atlantic"},
        {id: 17, name: "Bahia"},
      ],
      {
        theme: "facebook",
        showHintAsWatermark: true,
        hintText: "enter yacht type",
        noResultsText: "no results",
        searchingText: "searching...",
        preventDuplicates: true
      });
});
```

I have searched documentation pages and forums and did not found a similar problem. Maybe it is a jQuery version conflict, I do not know. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the plugin which has previously been fixed.

Update to the latest version (currently 1.6.2) from the [GitHub](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput) - the version loopj.com is only the last major revision - now several years old.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I checked before on the main project website and there was the same version I was using. There is even 1.7 version on the GitHub now, after update works fine!